# How can I get value from label text field which is dynamically changes JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

```
<Label fx:id="lblLibrarianId" layoutX="82.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="24.0"  prefWidth="212.0" text="$librarianId" />
```

I have a controller name `LibraryController`. I set label value text to `librarianId` dynamically from another controller. Now, I want to access this `librarianId` to `LibraryController`.

```
final FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../fxmlfile/librarian.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.getNamespace().put("librarianId", librarianId);
```

This is the way how I set the value dynamically to `Label text field`. Now I want to retrieve that `Label Text value` to my `LibraryController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, create your label object, and call getText()
you'll need to use the @FXML to associate that object with the fx:id in your .fxml file

ex.

```
public class LibraryController{

     @FXML public Label lblLibrarianId;
     public String librarianID;

     final FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../fxmlfile/librarian.fxml"));
     fxmlLoader.getNamespace().put("librarianId", librarianId);


     librarianId = lblLibrarianId.getText();


}
```